# Dúvida como enviar chamar um método em outra classe

Tags: c#, classes

Tenho uma classe cl_Calculo que tem um método que chama uma tabela em sql por uma classe CRUD já criada, e quero em um Form ao clicar em um botão chamar o método dessa classe passando o comando sql e que apresente o resultado em uma Message box.

```
namespace Calculos {
  public class cl_Calculos {

    public int[] Dezenas(int jogo, string query) {

      #
      region Apresenta as Dezenas do concurso consultado
      cl_GestorDB gestor = new cl_GestorDB();
      //string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.seq_concurso WHERE concurso = " + jogo;            
      DataTable dados = gestor.EXE_READER(query + "'" + jogo + "'");
      //-------------------------------------------            
      int dezena_1 = Convert.ToInt32(dados.Rows[0]["01"].ToString());
      int dezena_2 = Convert.ToInt32(dados.Rows[0]["02"].ToString());
      int dezena_3 = Convert.ToInt32(dados.Rows[0]["03"].ToString());

      int[] dezenas = new int[] {
        dezena_1,
        dezena_2,
        dezena_3,
      }; //Cria um array com as dezenas sorteadas
      #
      endregion
      //--------------------------------------------------------------            
      return dezenas;
    }

    namespace WindowsFormsApp7 {
      public partial class Form1: Form {
        private void btn_Teste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

          cl_Calculos Jogo = new cl_Calculos(10, "SELECT* FROM dbo.seq_concurso WHERE concurso = ");

          string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Jogo.Dezenas);
          MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);

        }
        //==================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp7 { 

    public partial class Form1 : Form { 

        private void btn_Teste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            _Calculos Jogo = new cl_Calculos();

            string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                   Jogo.Dezenas(10, 
                    "SELECT* FROM dbo.seq_concurso WHERE concurso = ");

            MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se seria a melhor solução, mas você poderia criar um método que receba a string de conexão como parametro e retorne a string, passando ela para o Messagebox.

Criando o método:

```
public string Resultado(string strQuery){
    _Calculos Jogo = new cl_Calculos();
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Jogo.Dezenas(10, strQuery);
}
```

No evento Click() do botão, você poderia chamar passando o método como parâmetro pra MessageBox:

```
private void btn_Teste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show(Resultado("SELECT* FROM dbo.seq_concurso WHERE concurso = "));
}
```

Usando este método, você pode alterar a string de consulta, quando for necessário.
Se quiseres, podes adicionar um int nos parâmetros do método para informar o número de dezenas também, ficaria mais ou menos desse jeito:

```
public string Resultado(int numDezenas, string strConsulta){
    _Calculos Jogo = new cl_Calculos();
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Jogo.Dezenas(numDezenas, strQuery);
}
```